# Animals that live in the country

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, phrase-request

I am creating a vocabulary worksheet about the British countryside with its natural and typical features, and I'm stuck on how best to classify the animals living wild in the country.

The list of animals, mostly mammals, include: *badgers*, *beavers*,  *deer*, *foxes*, *hedgehogs*, *owls*, *rabbits*, *sparrows*, *squirrel*s,  etc. 
Should I call them:

1. Woodland creatures (or animals)
2. Forest creatures (or animals)
3. Country animals
4. Countryside animals
5. Animals in the woods/woodland/country/forest
6. Wood animals (the least convincing of the lot because it sounds as if the animals are made of wood, but I include this option too)

Or do I simply call these animals *wildlife*? This would cover all the species, but I feel this is too large a group: I am sure lions, vultures, and crocodiles, to name but three,  are also included.

7. Wildlife

> **[wildlife](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wildlife?q=wildlife)**
>   animals, birds, insects, etc. that are wild and live in a natural environment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can only speak from experience, but as a person who grew up in a similar countryside to the one you describe, 'wildlife' is a perfectly suitable term to refer to wild animals specific to that area.

Perhaps a clearer definition of wildlife is this:

> wild animals collectively; the native fauna (and sometimes flora) **of
>   a region**.

The point being, that when we mention wildlife, we are referring to the wildlife of a specific geographical area. Yes, lions, vultures, and crocodiles are wildlife, but not of that region, and that distinction is implicit.

If you wish to make it absolutely clear, as mentioned in the comments, **'British Wildlife'** would be a perfectly acceptable term to use. The [British Wildlife Centre](https://www.britishwildlifecentre.co.uk/) uses this term to describe wildlife native to Britain (not to mention, in the name of their organisation).

Comment: So should I entitle it "British wildlife"? I would like to make that distinction clear. Would you mind including the link to the definition, or just the name of the dictionary? Thanks!

Comment: 'British Wildlife' would be perfectly acceptable I would think. And the [British Wildlife Centre](https://www.britishwildlifecentre.co.uk/) would probably agree :)

Answer (score 0):

You can say:
1. *British/English woodland animals*
2. *The animals of the British/English countryside*
3.*The UK wildlife* or
4. *Fauna of England*.

If you included farm animals, you could possibly use the term *livestock*

> **[livestock](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/stock)**
>   Farm animals such as cattle, pigs, and sheep, bred and kept for their meat or milk

Comment: @Mari-LouA I saw that you mentioned *Countryside animals* which I suppose are livestock!  And you didn't mention anything about a *title*.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I get your point!

Comment: If you could explain why you think "forest animals/creatures" might be unsuitable, I'll give an upvote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What kind of forest are we mentioning? Temperate deciduous forests or coniferous forests? A Tropical rainforest or maybe a Boreal forest?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd say British countryside... Yeh, that's possible. English is too broad!

Comment: @Mari-LouA Why not simply say: **The animals of the British/English countryside.** Or: **The UK wildlife.** Or: **The fauna of England.**

Comment: @SovereginSun I would say to say English countryside or fauna  is too narrow. It excludes any animal found in other parts of Britain such as Wild Cats, Welsh Mountain Ponies and White Tailed Sea Eagles but not in England.